# Поиск элемента массива с минимальным количеством повторов

Tags: java, алгоритм

Помогите, пожалуйста, с написанием алгоритма по поиску элементов в массиве с минимальным количеством повторов.
Суть задачи:

Ввести с консоли имя файла
Найти байт или байты с минимальным количеством повторов
Вывести их на экран через пробел
Закрыть поток ввода-вывода

Мой код:

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String filename = reader.readLine();
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
    byte[] list = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    inputStream.read(list,0,inputStream.available());
    for(Integer b : list){
        System.out.print(b + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Забыл указать, язык Java

Comment: Напишите также о том, что вы пробовали делать и что у вас не получилось, это даст больше информации о вашей проблеме

Comment: какой массив? строковый, числовой ? какой элемент массива искать? любой/максимальный/минимальный ?

Comment: у меня имеется байтовый массив, из него необходимо вывести на экран байты с минимальным количеством повторов.

Comment: в массив байтов я загружаю информацию из txt файла

Comment: @Evgeniy, добавьте больше информации в тело вопроса.

Comment: добавил условие и свой код.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Обновление**: заменил `Hashtable` на более современный `HashMap`.

---

Поскольку это явно учебное задание, подсказываю, но не даю код.

Вы должны для каждого введённого значения подсчитать количество его повторов. В общем случае для этого используется `Map`, который будет отображать байт на количество его повторов (например, [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)). При вводе нового числа увеличивайте количество его повторов.

После этого вам нужно будет пробежаться по всем количествам повторов, и найти среди них минимальное. (Очевидно, один цикл, если вы не используете streams API). После чего пробегитесь по элементам и выведите те, у которых записанное в `HashMap` количество повторов равно найденному минимуму.

---

Поскольку вашим типом данных элемента является байт, вы можете смоделировать `HashMap` массивом с индексами от 0 до 255. Но это, по идее, нужно только если пользоваться `HashMap` вам запрещено.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: @Evgeniy: Пожалуйста! Удачи!

Comment: И все же, поскольку **это байт**, то массив счетчиков (моделирующий hashtable) будет хорошим решением (а вот с Char уже надо задуматься).

Comment: @avp: Насколько я помню, в Java, как и в C#, `char` двухбайтный. То есть несчастные 64К памяти под счётчики — не запредельный расход, вполне себе можно. Но мне `Dictionary` кажется семантичнее.

Comment: Ага, 16 бит (unsigned). Если один такой массив на все приложение, то ерунда (imho обычно все же он займет 256K), но если это внутри библиотеки ...

Comment: Задачу решил только, что :) сделал через HashMap + HashSet.

Comment: @Evgeniy: Вот и отлично!

Comment: @avp: ну, если 4 байта на счётчик, то да. Но можно сэкономить и обойтись двумя байтами — больше, чем 65536 символов с клавиатуры преподаватель вряд ли введёт.

Comment: @VladD, не надо рекомендовать людям Hashtable. Он устарел. Нужен `HashMap`.

Comment: @TagirValeev: А почему? В документации ничего об этом не нашёл. ЗЫ: нашёл на en.SO, жаль, что оф. документация не упоминает об этом ничего.

Comment: @VladD, [обсуждалось](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-October/035734.html) буквально на днях разработчиками Java в мейлинг-листе. Возможно, сделают пометку в девятой джаве. Конечно, стыд, что до сих пор нет.

Answer (score 2):

Раз автор уже решил, могу и я ответ написать. Раз у вас на входе байты, вам не нужна хэш-таблица. Разных байтов всего 256. Гораздо проще и эффективнее завести тупой массив на 256 элементов и плюсовать каждый найденный байт. Потом найти в нём минимальное ненулевое число и вывести индексы элементов с этим значением.

Кстати, вы читаете файл в массив неправильно. Метод `inputStream.available()` не гарантирует, что выдаст вам весь файл. В конце концов файлы бывают хитрые (символьные устройства, именованные трубы и т. д.). Ну и вы даже не подтрудились его закрыть. Проще и надёжнее использовать `Files.readAllBytes()`.

Вот для примера полностью рабочий код на Java-8:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String inputFileName = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    int[] counts = new int[256];
    for (byte b : Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputFileName))) {
        counts[b & 0xFF]++;
    }
    OptionalInt minCount = Arrays.stream(counts).filter(x -> x > 0).min();
    if (minCount.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("Минимальное количество: " + minCount.getAsInt());
        IntStream.range(0, counts.length)
                .filter(b -> counts[b] == minCount.getAsInt())
                .forEach(idx -> System.out.printf("%02X ", idx));
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Файл пустой :(");
    }
}
```

Лучше, конечно, читать файл потоком, чтобы не тратить память, но это уже останется в качестве упражнения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! В данной задачи необходимо было пользоваться именно методом inputStream.available(), ну и в своем решении я конечно закрыл все потоки ввода-вывода :) А так Ваш код выглядит намного удобнее, мой значительно больше строк занял получилось 2 дополнительных метода :)